# Mockito and ScopedModel

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, scoped-model

I'm trying to fix a test since I have implemented ScopedModelDescendant to get data to fill up my page with information for the user.

The issue I'm facing is that it seems I can not mock ScopedModel with mockito. Somehow is asking me to specify some properties which does not occur with other classes I have been mocking so far.

[image: this is my build for the widget]

This is how my app is being configured

[image]

So far so good, my app is working properly and I can invoke ScopedModelDescendant anywhere without injecting anything in my widgets. But when running my test I'm getting this error

[image]

And this is how I'm configuring my test

[image]

I know I should be doinng something like this

```
class MockScopedModel extends Mock implements ScopedModel<MockMainModel>{}
```

But if I do that in order to mock sopedModel I get this error/warning

[image]

Does anyone know how to mock the scopedModel properly? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so  issue was I was not specifying the type for the scopeModel class in my test.

[Github ticket](https://github.com/brianegan/scoped_model/issues/107)

It is strange that in my code was not required to specify the type for my ScopedModel but in my test it did. Anyways I hope this helps anyone who might encounter this issue while testing.